# Object Does Not Match Target Type in Unit using Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, unity-game-engine

I am trying to use Reflection (first time for me and I have looked through many of the other answers for this error and not found one that works for me)

Here is the Calling Method

```
void OnMouseDown(){
    string CardName = "GoldFate";

    Type classType = Type.GetType(CardName);
    Debug.Log ("Type: " + classType);

    MethodInfo theMethod = classType.GetMethod("Resolve"+CardName);
    Debug.Log ("MethodInfo: " + theMethod);

    theMethod.Invoke(this, null);
}
```

Here is the target:

```
public class GoldFate {
    public void ResolveGoldFate(){
        Debug.Log ("We got to Gold Fate");
    }
}
```

The output this generates is:

**Type: GoldFate**

**MethodInfo: Void ResolveGoldFate()**

**TargetException: Object does not match target type.**
System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:236)
System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MethodBase.cs:115)
FateCardManager.OnMouseDown () (at Assets/Scripts/Card Manipulation/FateCards/FateCardManager.cs:53)
UnityEngine.SendMouseEvents:DoSendMouseEvents(Int32, Int32)

I do not get to the Debug Message obviously

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your problem lies here in this line: `theMethod.Invoke(this, null);`. Here the `this` needs to be an instance of `GoldFate` class. Once you have ensured that, I think you'll be able to invoke the method successfully.

Comment: This is correct, check my answer below for how to access a method that is not public.

Comment: Thank you for your help. 
Please not the edit i had to make. CardName is a string with the value "GoldFate"

Comment: In order to invoke a method using reflection, you need to have an instance of the class. To do that use `ConstructorInfo ctor= yourType.GetConstructor(...);
        object obj= ctor.Invoke(...);`. And then use this `obj` in `.Invoke` instead of `this`. 
For more details check the Example here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You Sir, are a legend.
I thank you for this 100% accurate answer.

Comment: Thank you @Wibble, that is so kind of you. :)

Answer (score 2):

The above solutions, streamlined:

```
var myClass =   new MyClass();

var method =    myClass.GetType().GetMethod( "MyMethod" );
if ( method != null )
    method.Invoke( myClass, null );
```

Thanks to your answers I was able to get this working in my code! <3